# How do I get the expectation values on the next line?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, expected-value

how do I get from the line at the start of the arrow to the next line?

[Picture of what I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVyHX.png)

I know that $E[X_{i-1}]=\sum_{x>0}x\text{Pr}[X_{i-1}=x]$ but don't know how to deal with the summations involving $x^2$ and $x\text{Pr}[X_{i-1}=x-1]$ stuff. How do they become $E[X_{i-1}]$ and $\frac{1}{100}$ mysteriously?

Comment: It's better to write out the question here, than to ask users to chase a picture offsite.  Help with formatting is at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with
\begin{align}
\sum_{x>0}x\Pr[X_{i-1}=x] - \frac{1}{100}\sum_{x>0}x\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1]\\
+\frac{1}{100}\sum_{x>0}x^2\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1] - \frac{1}{100}\sum_{x>0}x^2\Pr[X_{i-1}=x],\tag{*}
\end{align}
we can first note that
$$\sum_{x>0}x\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1] = \sum_{x>0}(x-1)\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1] + \sum_{x>0}\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1] = \mathbb{E}[X_{i-1}] + 1.$$
Therefore the first two terms of $(*)$ gives us
$$\sum_{x>0}x\Pr[X_{i-1}=x] - \frac{1}{100}\sum_{x>0}x\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1] = \frac{99}{100}\mathbb{E}[X_{i-1}] - \frac{1}{100}.$$
Next, we can use the same type of trick on the remaining two sums. Completing the square, we get
\begin{align}
&\sum_{x>0}x^2\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1]\\ 
&= \sum_{x>0}(x-1)^2\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1] + 2\sum_{x>0}x\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1]-\sum_{x>0}\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1]\\
&= \sum_{x>0}(x-1)^2\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1] + 2(\mathbb{E}[X_{i-1}]+1)-1\\
&= \sum_{x>0}(x-1)^2\Pr[X_{i-1}=x-1] + 2\mathbb{E}[X_{i-1}]+1.
\end{align}
The first of this latter sum cancels the last term of $(*)$, and we are left with
$$(*) = \frac{99}{100}\mathbb{E}[X_{i-1}] - \frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{100}(2\mathbb{E}[X_{i-1}]+1),$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much!